# How to Stop EC2 Instance from the list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, boto

I have the below code it is working very well in local for stopping EC2 Instance but while I am trying to move its production it is stopping only the first instance not the second one/nth one

```
import boto3
import json

access_key = "AKIAJSVXXXXXXXXXX"
secret_key = "mSvhX5q7uw8dTZ543qtC6OXXXXXXXXXXXX"
client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key, region_name='us-east-1')
file1 = open("Myfile.txt", "r").read().split("\n")
print(file1)

ec2_result = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Name',
            'Values': file1
            
        }
    ]
)


ids = [ec2_result['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][i]['InstanceId'] for i in
       range(len(ec2_result['Reservations'][0]['Instances']))]
print(ids)
response = client.stop_instances(
    InstanceIds=ids
)

print("stooped now")
```

Myfile.txt

```
instanceonename
instance2name
```

It is working very well in my local system but in production, it is stopping only the first EC2 instance
not second one

Comment: Make sure the instances are tagged properly. Make sure the tags that you expect are there in production match the ones you expect. Make sure that the instance-ids that you expect are showing up when you do `print(ids)`

Comment: print ids it is showing 
['instanceonename']

Comment: Check your tags again. Check if the `response` has any information/error or not. Check Ec2 termination protection status on the instance that doesn't get terminated

Comment: if I am doing print(file1)
it is showing
`` ['insatceone','instacne2', ' ']`` While there is no 3rd instance

Comment: @rdas it is working very well in prod if I am stopping the separate instance

Comment: when I am not reading from the file it is working very well for single instances @rdas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stops only one instance, because your list comprehension iterates only over one instance. You need **double for**:

```
ids = [instance['InstanceId'] \
         for reservation in ec2_result['Reservations'] \
         for instance in reservation['Instances']]
```

Comment: you are always my guide/Hero, thank you very much it is working now 
as always you made my day thanks sir thank you very much

Comment: @RahultheSWE No problem. Glad it works:-)

Comment: but I want to know the same code is working in my personal aws account but when it is prod it is showing this thing

Comment: @RahultheSWE Maybe because you have one instance in the prod account? Difficult to speculate. Most importantly, it works now.

Comment: I have 4000+ instance in prod :)